# No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined Using Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

How to i add the entity manager factory into the my configuration xml file.

```
<bean id="newDS" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.databaseurl}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />

    </bean>




<!-- Creating a Session Factory -->
    <bean id="localSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="newDS" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="test.impl.entities"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>



<!-- Transaction Manager  -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="localSessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean` with  `org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`

Comment: What are the other changes needed to add ..can you add the changes if i use this class i cannot use hibernate properties as well..

Comment: Instead of using <property name="hibernateProperties">, use <property name="jpaProperties">. The same properties you are using now will work inside jpaProperties.